# Passing arguments to awk script

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk

I have a awk script where i want to be able to pass N arguments into it and also read from stdin. I would like to be able to do something like

`tail -f logfile | my_cool_awk_scipt var1 var2 var3 ... varN`

And then use these variables inside the script.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
print "AWK Script Starting" 
print ARGV[1]
}                                                                              
{
    if ($0 < ARGV[1])
        print $0
    else if ($0 < ARGV[2])
        print $0 + ARGV[2]             
}
```

If i try to pass the variables as it stands it print `ARGV[1]` and then hits

```
awk: ./my_cool_awk_script:4: fatal: cannot open file `var1' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I can do,

```
tail -f logfile | my_cool_awk_scipt -v var1=var1 -v var2=var2 -v var3=var3 ... varN=varN
```

but this is a bit limiting and verbose. I know I can also wrap this in a shell script but am unsure a clean way to embed what I have into something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The moment awk hits the main body of the script, after `BEGIN`, it's going to want to read the filenames specified in ARGV[x].  So just nuke 'em.

```
$ cat a.awk
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
print "AWK Script Starting"
ZARGV[1]=ARGV[1]
ZARGV[2]=ARGV[2]
ARGV[1]=""
ARGV[2]=""
}
{
    if ($0 < ZARGV[1])
        print $0
    else if ($0 < ZARGV[2])
        print $0 + ZARGV[2]
}
$
```

Example:

```
$ cat logfile
1
2
3
4
5
$ ./a.awk 3 4 <logfile
AWK Script Starting
1
2
7
$
```

Comment: While the other Answers were good this was able to solve my problem in the most straight forward manner. Cheers

Comment: maybe something like `BEGIN{for(i in ARGV) ZARGV[i]=ARGV[i]; delete ARGV}` 
to handle an arbitrary number of arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it (and this is *certainly* NOT the recommended way to do it):
As `awk` doesn't know about "positional parameters" (PP) but only variable assignments and input filenames, we need to dissect the PP out and tell them from the other two. This could be done by either separating the PP with a fixed token, e.g. `--` (which is used in other context as well), or by knowing the PP count, either fixed or conveyed in e.g. ARGV[1]).
Try

```
    awk '
    BEGIN   {while (ARGV[++MXPP] != "--")   PP[MXPP]     = ARGV[MXPP]
             for (j=MXPP+1; j<ARGC; j++)    ARGV[j-MXPP] = ARGV[j]
             ARGC -= --MXPP
            }

            {if ($0 < ARGV[1])
             print $0
             else if ($0 < ARGV[2])
             print $0 + ARGV[2]             
            }
    ' VAR1 VAR2 -- file[12]
```

If you use stdin in lieu of input files by piping sth in, you could omit the token and fetch the PP until the end of the list (i.e. set token to "")

Answer (score 1):

You already know about `-v variable=value`.  The other way is to pass variables through the environment and read them from the `ENVIRON` array:

```
$ var1=hello var2=world awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["var1"], ENVIRON["var2"] }'
hello world
```

This sets the environment variables `var1` and `var2` in `awk`'s environment only.

Or,

```
$ export var1=hello var2=world
$ awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["var1"], ENVIRON["var2"] }'
hello world
```

This sets the variables in the calling environment before calling `awk`.

The `ARGV` array contains only the filenames that the `awk` program will read from in sequence, but it may also contain variable names set on the command line, as in

```
awk '...' var1=value1 var2=value2 filename
```

This is generally *not* a recommended way of passing variables into `awk` though (these variables would not be available in a `BEGIN` block for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You could build a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash   
vars=()
i=1
for arg in "$@"; do
    vars+=(-v "var$i=$arg")
    i=$((i+1))
done

awk "${vars[@]}" -f/dev/fd/3 3<< EOF
BEGIN {
    printf "awk var1: %s\n", var1;
    printf "awk var2: %s\n", var2;
}
1
EOF
```

and then run it:

```
$ echo some input | ./awk.sh foo bar doo
awk var1: foo
awk var2: bar
some input
```

The shell script will build a command line of those `-v var1=...` arguments, and pass those to `awk`, with the the actual awk program through a here-doc (of course you could have the awk script in a separate file  instead). You can't pass any names of the input files this way, though, you're forced to have the awk script read from stdin.

At least GNU awk explicitly documents that `ARGV[n]` are used as the input files too (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html), which is why you get the "file not found" errors.